# Best way to add left and right cols to responsive Bootstrap rows ? (with TWIG)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, twig

I use TWIG to render some HTML/Twitter Boostrap CSS code. I made an image gallery using this following code:

```
<section class="row align-items-center" style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">    
      {% for i in contents %}
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 text-center box">
        <a href="#">
          <img class="ownthumbnail" src="{{ asset('images/'~section~'/'~i) | imagine_filter('mini') }}" alt=":-)">
        </a>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
</section>
```

I would like, for some design reasons, to add automatically two columns (one left, one right like margins) per rendered rows independently from the size of the window (xs, sm, md or lg). **How would you tackle this problem ?**

EDIT: to be clear, what I get now is a gallery with 6 columns (col-lg-2), 4 columns (col-md-3), 3 columns (col-sm-4) or 1 column (col-xs-12) depending on the size of the screen. I want the same grid layout, but let the left and right columns empty. This would be ideally like this for the col-lg-2 case, with 9 images:

emp: empty
img: image

```
[empt][img1][img2][img3][img4][empt]
[empt][img5][img6][img7][img8][empt]
[empt][img9][empt][empt][empt][empt]
```

Comment: You mean colon or "column" ?

Comment: Columns, thx @GrzegorzKrauze

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my own question: I use JavaScript to setup dynamically the gallery. In the HTML I have a hidden "row" where my picture are. And when the windows is loaded or resized, I use the [ResponsiveBootstrapToolkit](https://github.com/maciej-gurban/responsive-bootstrap-toolkit) library to get the current Bootstrap's breakpoint and clone the hidden row with extra empty cols to get the layout I wish.

Answer (score 0):

For the class of your div tag you could set class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6". I hope this is working. It should set two columns in each row.

Comment: I edited my question to make things clearer. This is a question about how to dynamically keep rows empty, not just a layout matter.

Comment: in Bootstrap you have the possibility to use the class "col-md-offset-2" for example. If you put all 4 images of a row into a div tag you can set a offset for this tag. If you set for example class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" for each div tag or as you use in your code snippet section tag, it should work.

Comment: Right, but then I can't have empty columns, which I need for design purposes. Basically I want the top and bottom borders to appear, as if the all row where filled between two horizontal lines. With offset, these borders won't fill the entire page.

Comment: How do you set those borders?

Comment: style="border-top-style: solid; border-bottom-style: solid;" for each col

Comment: Do you have a mockup of how the result should look like?

Comment: Maybe you could set a <div> Tag all around the "image grid" with style="border-top-style: solid; border-bottom-style: solid;"